# File upload works, but can't move file to another directory

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, permissions, file-permissions

my project directory is /public_html/test/

ownership and permission are as below,

```
drwxrwsr-x 8 lamp apache 4096 Apr  8 10:46 public_html
drwxrwsr-x 6 lamp apache 4096 Apr  2 14:58 test
```

a web application create directory, upload some files, move files from one directory to other directory under directory /public_html/test/files/

```
drwxrwsr-x 21 lamp apache 4096 Apr 24 13:58 files
```

now the problem is,
I created directory called "mydirectory" using web application, it created under /public_html/test/files/ as below,

```
drwxrwsrwx 2 apache apache   4096 Apr 15 13:56 mydirectory
```

then I uploaded one file say "myfile.jpg", which by default get uploaded to /public_html/test/files/

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache 595284 Apr 15 13:58 myfile.jpg
```

then my code use php function "move_uploaded_file" to move file to /public_html/test/files/ to /public_html/test/files/mydirectory/ as below

```
move_uploaded_file('/public_html/test/files/myfile.jpg', '/public_html/test/files/mydirectory/myfile.jpg');
```

It doesn't work. how to fix this?

if I change ownership of /public_html/test/files/mydirectory/ to lamp:apache instead apache:apache, and then upload the file again, move_uploaded_file works fine.

note: user "lamp" belongs to "apache" group.

===================

PHP Safe_mode was ON, just made it OFF and it worked :)

Comment: ok try chmoding the file before moving it, sometime i get same problems like that to.. see if somthing happens: upload the file->chmod the file->move the file

Comment: it didn't help. also tried as suggested by javad_shareef and Robert Rozas. But it didn't work either.

Comment: maybe u should retort to copy(), but btw did u confirm that the file you are trying to copy exist/successfully uploaded?

Comment: yes. it's successfully uploaded. it's just failed on move.

Comment: any way to inherit ownership and permissions of parent?  /public_html/test/files/ is having ownership lamp:apache, and directory and files created under it by application is having apache:apache ownership. I think, if ownership retain from parent, this will work. but how to keep the ownership and permission same a parent?

Comment: ok, maybe u should use chmod then and just copy the permission setting from your paraent directory like chmod("file",0755) in php before you copy();

Comment: used copy(), but it's same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
move_uploaded_file('/public_html/test/files/myfile.jpg', '/public_html/test/files/mydirectory/myfile.jpg');
```

Should be like:

```
move_uploaded_file('/public_html/test/files/myfile.jpg', '/public_html/test/files/mydirectory');
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is not with permission. You are wrongly using move_uploaded_file() function.

Correct usage is

```
move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination )
```

Replace your code with this.

```
move_uploaded_file('/public_html/test/files/myfile.jpg', '/public_html/test/files/mydirectory');
```

For more details

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php